# import Errors sqldeveloper

Tags: csv, import, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting import errors from sqldeveloper. Can seem to find answers. This a csv file with about 465000 row. not sure if its the size but everything seems to checkout

Import Data into table GNS from file C:\Users\Quartey-Henry-K\Desktop\Telework Cert\GNS.csv . Task canceled and import rolled back. Statement Failed:  CREATE TABLE GNS ( RC NUMBER(3),  UFI NUMBER(8),  UNI NUMBER(8),  LAT NUMBER(4, 2),  LONGITUDE NUMBER(4, 2),  DMS_LAT VARCHAR2(9),  DMS_LONG VARCHAR2(9),  MGRS VARCHAR2(15),  JOG VARCHAR2(7),  FC VARCHAR2(1),  DSG VARCHAR2(5),  PC VARCHAR2,  CC1 VARCHAR2(2),  ADM1 NUMBER(1),  POP VARCHAR2,  ELEV VARCHAR2,  CC2 VARCHAR2,  NT VARCHAR2(2),  LC VARCHAR2(3),  SHORT_FORM VARCHAR2(12),  GENERIC VARCHAR2(16),  SORT_NAME_RO VARCHAR2(44),  FULL_NAME_RO VARCHAR2(46),  FULL_NAME_ND_RO VARCHAR2(46),  SORT_NAME_RG VARCHAR2(44),  FULL_NAME_RG VARCHAR2(46),  FULL_NAME_ND_RG VARCHAR2(46),  NOTE VARCHAR2,  MODIFY_DATE VARCHAR2(10),  DISPLAY NUMBER(9),  NAME_RANK NUMBER(1),  NAME_LINK NUMBER(8),  TRANSL_CD VARCHAR2(22),  NM_MODIFY_DATE VARCHAR2(10),  F_EFCTV_DT VARCHAR2(26),  F_TERM_DT VARCHAR2(26)) ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Comment: CC2 column is missing a size in the create table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the wizard isn't assigning a column size for 4 of your columns

```
CREATE TABLE gns (
    rc               NUMBER(3),
    ufi              NUMBER(8),
    uni              NUMBER(8),
    lat              NUMBER(4, 2),
    longitude        NUMBER(4, 2),
    dms_lat          VARCHAR2(9),
    dms_long         VARCHAR2(9),
    mgrs             VARCHAR2(15),
    jog              VARCHAR2(7),
    fc               VARCHAR2(1),
    dsg              VARCHAR2(5),
    pc               VARCHAR2,
    cc1              VARCHAR2(2),
    adm1             NUMBER(1),
    pop              VARCHAR2, -- needs a size
    elev             VARCHAR2, -- needs a size
    cc2              VARCHAR2, -- needs a size
    nt               VARCHAR2(2),
    lc               VARCHAR2(3),
    short_form       VARCHAR2(12),
    generic          VARCHAR2(16),
    sort_name_ro     VARCHAR2(44),
    full_name_ro     VARCHAR2(46),
    full_name_nd_ro  VARCHAR2(46),
    sort_name_rg     VARCHAR2(44),
    full_name_rg     VARCHAR2(46),
    full_name_nd_rg  VARCHAR2(46),
    note             VARCHAR2, -- needs a size
    modify_date      VARCHAR2(10),
    display          NUMBER(9),
    name_rank        NUMBER(1),
    name_link        NUMBER(8),
    transl_cd        VARCHAR2(22),
    nm_modify_date   VARCHAR2(10),
    f_efctv_dt       VARCHAR2(26),
    f_term_dt        VARCHAR2(26)
);
```

Try fixing up this DDL manually and running it in the SQL Worksheet. Then find the table on the left in the tree (you might have to refresh it), then right click on the table, select IMPORT and walk the wizard again.

Also, if NM_MODIFTY_DATE is actually a date, please consider the DATE or TIMESTAMP data type. Your SQL and data will be cleaner as a result.

Also, what version of SQL Developer are you using? I'd like to make sure in case there's a bug here I need to track down. Recent versions shouldn't have let you get to this point.